# How to avoid multiple event fire when WPF page is opened again?

Tags: c#, wpf, window, dispose

I have a frame and few pages in my WPF application.

My navigation is controlled by buttons. On each button I have click handler that creates new page with some parameters:

```
private void ButtonProductionAuto_OnClick(ref TechModbus, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameMain.Content = new PageProductionAuto(someobject, this);
}

private void ButtonProductionManual_OnClick(ref TechModbus, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameMain.Content = new PageProductionManual(someobject, this);
}
```

When I'm switching between pages - previous pages still exist in memory and they react on some custom events.

(edit)

This is my code related with events:

```
public PageProductionAuto(ref TechModbus modbus, MainWindow wnd)
{        
    // ...

    wnd.KeyDown += Wnd_KeyDown;
    wnd.KeyUp += Wnd_KeyUp;
    m.OnReadFinished += Modbus_OnReadFinished;

    // ...
}
```

How can I dispose these pages or how can I avoid double-fire on my events when page is opened second time?

Comment: Show us the code for `PageProductionAuto` or `PageProductionManual`

Comment: @KosalaW I have added code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should unregister the events on leaving the page.

GarbageCollector will then `"dispose"` (it's actually not a dispose) by itsself when there are no more references on those objects(`PageProductionAuto` and `PageProductionManual`).

Quoting MS:
The reason WPF controls don't implement IDisposable is because they have nothing to dispose. They have no handle to clean up, and no unmanaged resources to release. To ensure your memory is cleaned up, just make sure nothing has a reference to the controls once you're finished with them.

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem. OP is asking "how to dispose".

Comment: But it's a very very very bad practice to not unregister and then dispose those objects. It's the only reasonable solution to this i think.

Comment: Yes. Detaching events is a good practice. But this question is about how to dispose, and how to control having multiple instances.

Comment: Please provide the URL source of where that quote came from and consider formatting it as an actual quote with `>` chars.

Comment: OK. To say it more clearly: You can not dispose WPF elements, because there is no reason for them to be disposeable. If you want to do that you need to write your own wpf controls and implement IDisposeable.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is incomplete. But I can answer the question about "how to avoid multiple instances" part of it. To dispose your pages, you have to detach your events, remove them from the "openedPages" collection, and dispose where possible.

```
List<object> openedPages = new List<object>();

private void ButtonProductionAuto_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var page = openedPages.FirstOrDefault(p => p.GetType().Equals(typeof(PageProductionAuto)));
    if(page == null)
    {
        page = new PageProductionAuto(someobject, this);
        opendPages.Add(page);
    }
    else
    {
        page.SetObjects(someobject, this); // create a method to set "someObject" to your page.
    }

    FrameMain.Content = page;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did to avoid this was I have a window with 2 frames in it.  I placed one of each source XAML in each frame so frame 1 was XAML 1 and frame 2 was XAML 2.  Then I just edited the visibility to collapsed and visible.  Then you don't have any page changes or instances getting created.  You just create the original 2 instances.